# Override SaveChanges() not called in ASP .NET/EFCore 3.0

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to override the SaveChanges method in a DbContext, but my override code is never being called. Breakpoints set in the code are never hit, yet VsCode, when looking up the references indicates that it should be called.

My override function is in a separate file, as a partial class.

```
namespace Tracker.Models
{
    public partial class TrackerModel : DbContext {
        public override int SaveChanges() {
            this.SetCreatedUpdatedTimes();    
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void SetCreatedUpdatedTimes() {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            var entries = ChangeTracker
                .Entries()                
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

            foreach (var entityEntry in entries) {
                entityEntry.Property("UpdatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;

                if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added) {
                    entityEntry.Property("CreatedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is being called from the controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Tracker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Tracker.Controllers
{
    public partial class DatastoreController : Controller {

        private readonly TrackerModel _context;

        public DatastoreController(TrackerModel context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public ActionResult<Datastore> PostDatastore([FromBody]Datastore Datastore) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest("Invalid data.");

            _context.Add(Datastore);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Datastore;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything looks to be in the correct place. I am using EFCore 3.0 and ASP .NET Core 3.0.

Has anyone had trouble with this before and have any ideas on a resolution?

I have been using the implementation at the following blog as a guide (amongst others): https://www.ryansouthgate.com/2019/03/18/ef-core-databse-auditing/

Thanks

Comment: I'd double check `base.SaveChanges();` I think (emphasis on think) that using `base` will skip your overridden method and instead calls the non-overridden implementation of `SaveChanges();`

Comment: I've just tried ```this.SaveChanges()``` too, but same results.

Comment: there are multiple savechange methods you need to override

Comment: Sorry, I should have said. I have overridden 4 methods in total. I omitted them for brevity. I have breakpoints on all 4, and none of them are being hit. The signatures of all of the methods match those at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-3.0

Comment: Please show how you're creating the context and calling this method.

Comment: I have added an example above.

Comment: Are you certain that your `PostDataStore` method is being called?  Do you have a breakpoint in that method?  What happens when you step into the `_context.SaveChanges()` call?

Comment: In the constructor for the controller, there's a parameter for your context. Is that being set by dependency injection? Perhaps you could show us how that your instance is being registered in your unity container.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - you may be on to something. I was certain the PostDatastore method was being called, but having just added two breakpoints on the ```_context.Add(Datastore); _context.SaveChanges();``` lines, I have found that the Add is being called, and then that appears to perform a redirect, so the Save is never called. Same behaviour with an Update function too. I wasn't expecting those to have that behaviour.

Comment: Annoyingly I have not managed to work this out yet, however, a brand new project works using exactly the structure above. I need to compare the exact details. The above project has been updated from 2.2 to 3.0, so I wonder if something has been missed.